# Dropdown-List value calculation

Tags: excel-2013

Is it possible to create a drop down list with one number as source, and calculate the other values?

Here's what I mean:
[image: Example picture]

- Source is A1.
- B1 Dropdown-List's start value is 0 and maximum value is A1.
- Values to A1 (4 in that case) should be calculated with 0 as start value. (1, 2, 3 in that case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it in Excel 2010, but I think there will be no significant difference in Excel 2013.

1. Create a list of all eventually possible values (for example 0-1000). Assume that the values are located at `H1:H1001`.
2. Choose a cell in which a threshold will be held. Suppose it will be `F3`.
3. Restrict possible values in `F3`.

   - Select `F3`.
   - On the **Data** menu, click **Validation**.
   - In the **Allow** box, click **List**.
   - Uncheck the **In-cell drop-down** check box.
   - In the **Source** box, enter `=H1:H1001`.
4. Create a drop-down menu for a given cell.

   - Select a given cell.
   - On the **Data** menu, click **Validation**.
   - In the **Allow** box, click **List**.
   - Check the **In-cell drop-down** check box.
   - In the **Source** box, enter `=INDIRECT("H1:H"&(F3+1))`.
5. Voilà!

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3DD8D33B5647AC40!6502&authkey=!AHn-3c_QFxU-M9A&ithint=file,.xlsx) is a working example. Feel free to download it.

`INDIRECT` function accepts a string reference to a range and returns the range itself. So if value stored in F3 were 27, the function, as used here, would return a range from H1 to H28 (thus possibilities in the drop-down list would be 0-27).